# How to make onclick event on button inside card that: Change card background color, button background and text color and text content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of cards inside a container and one button inside each card. If I click the button I want to change the background color of the card that button is inside as well as change the background color of the button, the text content and text color of the button as well and keep it in that state until another button is pressed. Then the changes applied to whatever button was pressed (and their card as well).

```css
/* Cards */

.container-fluid {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 1855px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-left: -3.5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.col-centered {
  float: left;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 72%;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  width: 25em;
  height: 13em;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.card-tittle-font {
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card-info {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font: Roboto;
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.cardicon {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #0B8149;
}

.buttonsCards {
  font: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  transform: translate(-10%, 250%);
}


/*Details */

.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

clear {
  clear: both;
}


/*Card Highlight */

.highlight {
  background-color: #E2FDF1;
}

.card-highlight {
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

.card-highlight:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #E2FDF1;
}

.container-fluid:hover .card-highlight:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.buttonsCards:houver span {
  display: none;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.buttonsCards::after {
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
  content: "Selecionar";
}

.buttonsCards:hover::after {
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
  content: "Selecionado";
  color: white;
  background-color: #0B8149;
}

.buttonsCards:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/*Details */

.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=col-1></div>
      <div class=col-10>

        <div class="container-fluid mt-4 justify-content-between">
          <div class="row col-centered">
            <div class="col-4 mb-3 ">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                    <span class="bi bi-card-image cardicon" style="vertical-align: middle"></span>
                    <span class="card-tittle-font" style="margin-left:10px">
                                            Imagens
                                        </span>
                  </h5>
                  <div class="left">
                    <p class="card-text card-info">FORMAT </br>
                      <a style="color: black;">JPEG, JPG, PNG...</a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="left">
                    <p class="card-text card-info ">Details</br>
                      <a style="color: black;">None</a>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="buttonsCards btn btn-success right" style="color: #0B8149;">Selecionar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mb-3 ">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                    <span class="bi bi-card-image cardicon" style="vertical-align: middle"></span>
                    <span class="card-tittle-font" style="margin-left:10px">
                                            Imagens
                                        </span>
                  </h5>
                  <div class="left">
                    <p class="card-text card-info">FORMAT</br>
                      <a style="color: black;">JPEG, JPG, PNG...</p></a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="left">
                    <p class="card-text card-info ">DETAILS</br>
                      <a style="color: black;">None</a>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="buttonsCards btn btn-success right" style="color: #0B8149;">Selecionar</button>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>



          </div>

          <div class=col-1></div>

        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I'm usign the bootstrap puglin in the Visual Code Studio (Bootstrap 4 snippets based on documentation + Font awesome 4 + Font Awesome 5 Free & Pro snippets)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There are probably a handful of ways this can be done.
But here's what I'd say is the simplest or easiest way that this can be achieved. It'll work with more than 2 cards as well - 100 if you like. Or more.

**1.** First, we need to listen for whenever the user clicks one of the buttons. When we realize a button has been clicked, we want to reset the . Then we want to add your specific styles to the card that contained the button that was clicked.

**You'd do it like this:**

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll("div.card");
    // returns a Nodelist Object of every card

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("div.card button");
    // returns a Nodelist Object of every button in a card

function resetCards() {
    // loops through each card
    cards.forEach(card => {
        // Makes the card and the button go to original look

        // Change this to your own default colour for the card and button
        card.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        card.querySelector("button").style.backgroundColor = "white";

        // Change button's text back to Selecionar (default)
        card.querySelector("button").innerText = "Selecionar";

        // Change button's text colour back to black (default)
        card.querySelector("button").style.color = "black";
    });
}

// Loops through every card
cards.forEach(card => {
    /* 
    Attaches an event listener to every button
    In simple language, it does something when you click a button
    */
    card.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {
        // When you click a button, the following code is executed

        // First it invokes (calls) the resetCards function - this will make all the cards go back to normal
        resetCards();

        // Makes the card which contains the button you clicked become blue
        // --- Change this to your own colour to add to the card when you clicked its button
        card.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

        // e.target tells you what you clicked.
        // In this case, you are always clicking the button so e.target returns the button you clicked
        
        // Makes the button you clicked have a lightblue background
        // --- Change this to your own colour for your button when you clicked
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";

        // Replace [something else] with the text you want for the button when it is clicked
        e.target.innerText = "something else";

        // Change the text colour for the button to the colour *you* want to use
        e.target.style.color = "red";
    });
});
```

That is method 1.

**Explanation**
First we make a variable called cards to contain a list of all the cards.
We do the same for all the buttons inside a card.

Next, we go through every card and tell the program to listen for when the user clicks one of the buttons. When this happens, we reset every card (as well as its button) to its default colour by calling the resetCards() function. Finally, we add a specific background colour to the card that contains the button we clicked. We then add another colour to the button that we clicked. That's it. Then, when you click another card, the program will again reset all the cards and then add the specific colours to the card and button you just clicked.

**Hope this helps you with what you're trying to achieve. This was my first answer so it was quite interesting doing this. Have a great day.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly and your explation was really helpfull and detailed. It will sure help me on future projects! c;

Comment: Glad to hear it!